# T-SQL CROSS APPLY INTO THE SAME TABLE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've got a table:

```
Col1  Col2  Col3
----  ----  ----
 A     AA    dfdf
 A     BB    jhf
 A     CC    lkji
 B     AA    jkl
 B     CC    ioeu
 B     DD    sjdf
 C     AA    zkjjj
```

What I want is to find the complete set of Col2, and then add it into the table again for each Col1, leaving all the other fields NULL/blank.

I've got a solution using 4 tables (a distinct table of Col1, distinct table of Col2, then a CROSS APPLY into table 3, finally inserting any missing records into my original source table), but I feel that I could do this without them, if I just figure it out. That's where I got stuck.

So in the above example, I'd end up with

```
Col1  Col2  Col3
----  ----  ----
 A     AA    dfdf
 A     BB    jhf
 A     CC    lkji
 A     DD    
 B     AA    jkl
 B     BB
 B     CC    ioeu
 B     DD    sjdf
 C     AA    zkjjj
 C     BB   
 C     CC   
 C     DD
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach you describe (your "4 tables") is quite okay, but you can use *ad-hoc* sql by using `CTEs` rather than tables. Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Col1 VARCHAR(10),Col2 VARCHAR(10),Col3 VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('A','AA','dfdf')
,('A','BB','jhf')
,('A','CC','lkji')
,('B','AA','jkl')
,('B','CC','ioeu')
,('B','DD','sjdf')
,('C','AA','zkjjj');

WITH Distinct1 AS(SELECT DISTINCT Col1 FROM @tbl)
    ,Distinct2 AS(SELECT DISTINCT Col2 FROM @tbl)
INSERT INTO @tbl(Col1,Col2,Col3)
SELECT d1.Col1,d2.Col2,NULL
FROM Distinct1 AS d1
CROSS APPLY Distinct2 AS d2
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @tbl WHERE Col1=d1.Col1 AND Col2=d2.Col2);

SELECT * FROM @tbl
ORDER BY Col1,Col2
```

**hint:** Whenever a table **must include all possible combinations** of subsets, this might be an indicator for a bad design...

Comment: Thank you Shnugo! This is exactly what I was trying to write. A bit of background if you were curious, We're hosting around 60 DB's, and they have "patch history" tables. We use Excel to grab the list from an SP that creates the DB names and patches on them. I got asked for "A list of DB's and missing patches." This approach avoids needing a table (or list in Excel) that has to contain an up to date list of patches(that would never be updated). Instead - by sticking a patch on one server, the rest in Excel will show as missing that patch. It's a little 2 day project. Thanks again!

Comment: @SarahC Ah, I see... Happy Coding!